# Error when running app in iOS5 for facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5, ios6

I am using [DeFacebookComposeViewController](https://github.com/sakrist/FacebookSample) to share pictures in facebook. It is running fine in iOS6. But have issue running in iOS5.

I put a breakpoint in this function:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);

    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Url is returning this error:

```
://authorize/?error_code=901&error_message=This+app+is+in+sandbox+mode.++Edit+the+app+configuration+at+http%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fapps+to+make+the+app+publicly+visible.#_=_
```

Moreover, when in iOS5, after I log in and post my image and text, it returns me back to the app instead actually posting the image to Facebook.

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: Is the Facebook account you are using a developer/tester for the Facebook app? If not, the FB app won't be publicly visible.

Comment: a developer/tester for the Facebook app...